# Android: NullPointerException at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(ActivityThread.java:1012)

Tags: android, service, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I am getting a

`NullPointerException at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(ActivityThread.java:1012)`

My application is not even in the stack trace, so I have no idea what is going on.

I am trying to connect to a service when it happens.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can we see a code snippet of you trying to connect to the service?

Answer (score 7):

This probably way too old for my response to be of any use, but in case anybody else has this problem, here's what it was for me.  I am using a newer version of the SDK, so I'm getting this issue at line 1061.

It was happening to me because I was passing a null ServiceConnection object to the function bindService.

It was helpful to browse the SDK code in my case - although the line numbers don't add up due to version differences, the general code is likely the same (and I knew which method to check):

```
1097                 // If there was an old service, it is not disconnected.
1098                 if (old != null) {
1099                     mConnection.onServiceDisconnected(name);
1100                 }
1101                 // If there is a new service, it is now connected.
1102                 if (service != null) {
1103                     mConnection.onServiceConnected(name, service);
1104                 }
```

mConnection was pretty much the only thing that made sense to be null.